# Active,Notifying feature is not working in Worklight 6.2

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-console

I was trying to notify the users of a specific version using Active, Notifying feature in Worklight console (Wl 6.2).  It was not successful and the below message was thrown in the logs.
We have recently updated the iFix from IBM (Worklight v6.2.0.1 InterimFix 201511281300). Since we are trying this feature for first time , not sure if this because of this fix. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Server Logs:

```
      [12/11/15 8:59:58:564 SGT] 00000127 com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction              E RuntimeMBeanCallable.call() exception
```

java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at $Proxy213.setAccessRule(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.ApplicationEnvironmentAccessRuleChangeTransaction.prepareMBean(ApplicationEnvironmentAccessRuleChangeTransaction.java:170)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.util.RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller$RuntimeMBeanCallable.call(RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller.java:75)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.util.RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller.callSynchronously(RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller.java:182)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.util.RuntimeMBeanPoolCaller.callRuntimeMBeans(RuntimeMBeanPoolCaller.java:93)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction.prepare(BaseTransaction.java:395)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction.internalRun(BaseTransaction.java:311)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction.run(BaseTransaction.java:227)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.ApplicationEnvService.setVersionAccessRuleInternal(ApplicationEnvService.java:657)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.ApplicationEnvService.setVersionAccessRule(ApplicationEnvService.java:514)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:34)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:183)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:110)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:52)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1240)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:760)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:88)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:61)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.filter.HSTSFilter.doFilter(HSTSFilter.java:110)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1029)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4499)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:954)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:584)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:439)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:421)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidObjectException: No constructor has a @ConstructorProperties for this set of items: [action, createdTime, downloadLink, message, multiLanguageMessagesJSON]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory$CompositeBuilderViaConstructor.fromCompositeData(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory$CompositeMapping.fromNonNullOpenValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory$NonNullMXBeanMapping.fromOpenValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.fromOpenParameters(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.jmx.service.MBeanServerForwarderDelegate.invoke(MBeanServerForwarderDelegate.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.jmx.internal.DelayedMBeanActivator.invoke(DelayedMBeanActivator.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.kernel.boot.jmx.internal.PlatformMBeanServer.invoke(PlatformMBeanServer.java:272)
    at com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.server.rest.helpers.MBeanServerHelper.invoke(MBeanServerHelper.java:159)
    at com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.server.rest.resources.MBeanResource.invocation(MBeanResource.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:34)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:188)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:110)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodWADLHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodWADLHandler.java:51)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:75)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:124)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1240)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:760)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.wab.internal.OsgiDirectoryProtectionFilter.doFilter(OsgiDirectoryProtectionFilter.java:96)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1029)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:78)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:885)
    ... 5 more

Activity Log:
          Transaction 13752
    type: SET_APPLICATION_ENV_VERSION_ACCESS_RULE
    status: FAILURE
    dateCreated : 2015-12-11T00:59:58.361Z
    dateUpdated: 2015-12-11T00:59:59.297Z
    server: Liberty
    description: 
        appVersion: 
            applicationName: ABCD
            environment: iphone
            version: 1.0
        action: NOTIFY
        createdAtDate: 2015-12-11T00:59:58.299Z
        downloadLink: 
        message: hello
    errors: 
        1 :
            mbeanName: com.worklight.common.server.jmx.api:qualifier=ABCD,type=ProjectManagement_KOM-MAP-WLSRV
            date: 2015-12-11T00:59:58.627Z
            phase: PREPARE
            code: FAILURE
            exception: UndeclaredThrowableException
            details: UndeclaredThrowableException

Answer (score 0):

The exception clearly indicates a problem at either creating of saving the active notify rule. Please open a PMR so that it will be investigated and resolved. You'll then receive an iFix...

Comment: Thanks for the help Idan.